# Retrieve the tag string in the step definition file

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Dear members of the forum, I currently run the cucumber tests through the following command:

```
cucumber --tags @foo
```

Now I shall retrieve the tag string "foo" and create an object of class "foo" in the first line of the step definition file. Something like this

my_step_definition.rb

```
1. my_object = string_retrieved_from_tags.new
```

How can I accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't use cucumber but in ruby you can retrieve command line arguments by accessing `ARGV` in your code. That might give you what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Dan Hilton said you can easily accomplish this like so:

```rb
tags_index = ARGV.index '--tags'
tag = ARGV[tags_index + 1] # the tags are listed after the tag argument in the args array
tag = tag[1..-1] # Remove '@' from the tag.
my_object = tag.constantize.new
```